# Simple blackjack

Tags: java, eclipse

Here's the question: Given 2 int values greater than 0, return whichever value is nearest to 21 without going over. Return 0 if they both go over.

```
blackjack(19, 21) → 21
blackjack(21, 19) → 21
blackjack(19, 22) → 19
```

What I have so far:

```
 public int blackjack(int a, int b) {
  if (a>21 && b>21){
  return 0;
  }
  if (a<21 && b>21){
  return a;
  }
  if (b<21 && a>21){
  return b;
  }
  if (21-a < 21-b){
  return a;
  }
  return b;
}
```

This question is from codingbat.com, and for all the tests that it shows, this code works, but when it finishes and displays "other tests", this code fails. I suppose there's a certain situation where this wouldn't work, but I can't think of it right now. Any thoughts?

Comment: If a is 18 and b is 19 what does your program return and why? Isn't the number closest to 21 at the bottom the largest number?

Comment: You're missing the cases where at least one is exactly 21.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public int blackjack(int a, int b) {
// if both a and b are outside the valid range
if (a > 21 && b > 21)
  return 0;

// if a is within the valid range but b is not
if (a <= 21 && b > 21)
  return a;

// if b is within the valid range but a is not
if (b <= 21 && a > 21)
  return b;

// if both a and be are within the valid range
return (a-b >= 0) ? a : b;

// Alternative: return Math.max(a, b);    ---as per SimonT in the comment
}
```

So I guess your issue is that you didn't include 21 in your conditions.

Comment: For the last line, why not `return Math.max(a,b);`?  Or `return (a > b) ? a : b;`

Comment: It's code on a website and I wasn't sure if you could use libraries so I went with straight logic :)

Answer (score 1):

If a=21, b=22, then it will return b which is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to specify the `=` operation in your condition. Change 2nd and 3rd condition to :

```
if (a<=21 && b>21){
  return a;
}
if (b<=21 && a>21){
  return b;
}
```